# информационная страница bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, как можно с помощью бустрапа сделать простую адаптивную информационную страничку как на скриншоте? и чтобы можно было в подразделы переходить сразу при помощи ссылки, типа: /menu/category1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Похожий пример реализован прямо на сайте bootstrap:

http://bootstrap-ru.com/examples/fluid.html

Убери лишние блоки, можешь подкорректировать вид под себя...

http://bootstrap-ru.com/getting_started.php